# IBM datastage integration with java

Tags: datastage

We have datastage jobs and want to use one java class which reads the file and gives some data back. Can someone explain the steps needed to perform this function?

Answer (score 2):

There are java transformer and java client stages in Real Time section in Palette.
You will need to study the API that DataStage uses to work with Java.
Simply write a java code that reads the file and you can call its class in DataStage.

Comment: It would be good to see an example for both these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Integration Stage is a DataStage Connector through which you can call a custom Java application from InfoSphere Data Stage and Quality Stage parallel jobs. The Java Integration Stage is available from IBM InfoSphere Information Server version 9.1 and higher. The Java Integration Stage can be used in the following topologies: as a source, as a target, as a transformer, and as a lookup stage. For more information on the Java Integration Stage, see [Related topics](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1305handling/index.html#artrelatedtopics).

The DataStage Java Pack is a collection of two plug-in stages, Java Transformer and Java Client, through which you can call Java applications from DataStage. The Java Pack is available from DataStage version 7.5.x and higher.

The Java Transformer stage is an active stage that can be used to call a Java application that reads incoming data, transforms it, and writes it to an output link defined in a DataStage job. The Java Client stage is a passive stage that can be used as a source, as a target, and as a lookup stage. When used as a Source, the Java Client will be producing data. When used as a target, the Java Client Stage will be consuming data. When used as a lookup, the Java Client Stage will perform lookup functions.

For more information on the Java Pack Stages, see [Related topics](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1305handling/index.html#artrelatedtopics).

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1305handling/index.html